# specific view on ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view

ok here is the thing i have the view store that shows all the buildings. all i want to do is to show me only the buildings with the status "for sale"

in views store i have:

```
<% if notice%>
<p id="notice"> <%= notice%></p>
<%end%>

<h1>All Priorities</h1>

 <%= form_tag  store_path, :method => 'get'  do %>
<p>
  <%=text_field_tag :search , params[:search]%>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", :name=> nil%>
  </p>
  <%end%>

<% if @buildings.present? %> 
 <% @buildings.each do |building| %> 
<div class="entry">
    <div class="img">
    <%= image_tag (building.photo.url)%></div>
    <div class=" disc">
    <h3>Name of the Bulding:  <%= building.title %></h3>
     <h4>Status: <%= building.status %></h4>
    Info: <%=sanitize(building.description)%>
    <div class="price_line">
        <span class="price">Price: <%= sprintf("€ %0.02f",building.price)%></span><br/>
        <div class="button">
        <%= button_to("I want to see it", {:controller => "seeits", :action => "new", :building_id => building.id})%></div>

    </div> 

    <div class="pages">
    <%= will_paginate @buildings %></p>
    </div>

    </div>
<% end %>

</div>

<% else %> does not much try another name<% end %>
```

in controller>buildings_controller

```
 def index 

    @buildings = Building.all

      respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @buildings }
    end

  end


  # GET /buildings/1
  # GET /buildings/1.json
  def show
    @building = Building.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @building }
    end
  end
```

is there to do it with IF statement ? or i have to change `<% @buildings.each do |building| %>` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to filter your list of buildings would be to filter it in your view:

```
@buildings.select{|b| b.status == "for sale"}.each do |building|
```

However, this still requires you to query the DB for all your items - which is inefficient. Your views should be as simple as possible, and this isn't the [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) Rails way to do things.

A more robust way would be to use a `where` clause in your controller:

```
@buildings = Building.where("status = 'for sale'")
```

However, this still puts too much logic in your controller. Your model should be able to handle all of the query logic for you. The best way would be to create a [Rails scope](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#working-with-scopes) on your `Building` model:

```
class Building < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  scope :for_sale, where(:status => "for sale")
  ...
end
```

Then, in your controllers (or views) you would only have to do:

```
@buildings = Building.for_sale
```

Comment: is not working. is it posible to change  with IF statement or to change <% @buildings.each do |building| %> ? because i will make another view for rent,sold etc.....

Comment: i have use in views: @buildings.collect({ |b| b.status == "for sale" }).each do |building| but i got error : C:/Sites/projectproperties/app/views/store/index.html.erb:15: syntax error, unexpected '|', expecting '}' @buildings.collect({ |b| b.status == "for sale" }).... ^ C:/Sites/projectproperties/app/views/store/index.html.erb:15: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting keyword_end ...({ |b| b.status == "for sale" }).each do |building|

Comment: `@buildings.collect{|b| b.status == "for sale"}.each do |building|` - whoops, bad bracketing.

Comment: now it gets me error on <%= image_tag (building.photo.url)% (photo=undefined method `photo' for false:FalseClass) and then i remove that line for check and goes on title etc....

Comment: Whoops again - should be `.select`, rather than `.collect`. Updated the answer.